# Automatic culling in blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, image

I'm trying to render a scene where a large amount of the scene is visible, but blender has a performance feature where it culls objects when they start to get a certain distance from the camera, whether it be the actual render camera or user camera. Is there any way to remove this? I'm including a picture of the rendered scene.[image: Render I'm trying to make, failed due to auto-culling.]

EDIT> I found out right after posting this how to fix the problem.

Comment: Why doesn't setting the cull distance really high work for you?

Comment: Well... It did work, I just didn't know how to do it until a couple minutes after I posted this, thought I deleted it before anyone could see it, guess I was too slow. XD

Thanks for trying to help though, I appreciate it!